# Probability at least one will be profitable

Tags: probability, statistics

There are two investment portfolios, A and B. Portfolio A has 50% probability to be profitable, while Portfolio B has 80% probability to be profitable. The two portfolios are independent. What is the probability that at least one portfolio is profitable?

Comment: Hint: What is the probability both go bad? (The independence assumption is very unreasonable.)

Answer (score 1):

B has a $80$% chance of success and $20$% chance of failure.
If it is in the $20$% chance of failure, then there is still a $50$% chance that A can still succeed. So the probability is $0.8+0.2\cdot0.5=0.9=90\%$

Answer (score 0):

let $P(n)$ represent the probability that exactly $n$ investments are profitable, so that

$$ P(0)+P(1)+P(2) =1 $$

if you assume independence then the probability that both are profitable is $P(2) = (0.5)(0.8)=0.4$

The probability that neither are profitable is $P(0) = ( 1-0.5)(1-0.8)=0.1$

The probability that at least one is profitable is $P(1)+P(2)= 1 - P(0) = 1 - 0.1 = 0.9$

You could do a consistency check .$P(1)= P(\text{ A Good and B Bad})+P( \text{ A Bad and B Good })$

$$P(1) = (0.5)(1-0.8)+ (1-0.5)(0.8) = 0.1+0.4=0.5 $$

so that 
$$ P(0)+P(1)+P(2) =0.1+ 0.5 + 0.4 =1 $$